# How to use array reduce to sort data

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

How tu use reduce array to sort entries date here:

```
const entries = [
  {date: 'lu'},
  {date: 'lu'},
  {date: 'ma'},
  {date: 'ma'}
]
```

where output count occurence of date

```
const data = [
  {x: 'lu', y: 2},
  {x: 'ma', y: 2},
  {x: 'me', y: 0},
  {x: 'je', y: 0},
  {x: 've', y: 0},
  {x: 'sa', y: 0},
  {x: 'di', y: 0},
]
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: SO isn't a free code writing service; it was meant to help users with errors. Please show us what you tried and what your error is if any.

Answer (score 0):

Two nested forEach will do. Because you need to have the x an y values for each days even if it does not appear in the entries. So reduce won't do.

So you need to set a *starter* data array of objects for each days... Then loop the entries against every days.

```js
const entries = [
  {date: 'lu'},
  {date: 'lu'},
  {date: 'ma'},
  {date: 'ma'}
]

const data = [
  {x: 'lu', y: 0},
  {x: 'ma', y: 0},
  {x: 'me', y: 0},
  {x: 'je', y: 0},
  {x: 've', y: 0},
  {x: 'sa', y: 0},
  {x: 'di', y: 0},
]

entries.forEach(entry => {
  data.forEach(d => {
    if(d.x === entry.date){
      d.y++
    }
  })
})

console.log(data)
```